# Retrieve dataset from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pytorch, dataset

I have a function that splits a dataset in a non-iid setting. This function returns a dict of the labels:

```
def noniid(dataset, clients, min, max, equal_amount=False):
  len_dataset = len(dataset)
  samples_per_client = int(len_dataset/clients)
  idx = np.arange(len_dataset) #idx([0, 1, 2, ..., 59999])
  dict_users = {i: list() for i in range(clients)}

  if equal_amount==False: #different clients can hold vastly different amounts of data
    random_num_size = np.random.randint(min, max+1, size=clients)
    print(f"Total number of samples owned by clients : {sum(random_num_size)}")

    # total dataset should be larger or equal to sum of splitted dataset.
    assert len_dataset >= sum(random_num_size)

    if (len_dataset == sum(random_num_size)): #each sample will be used 
      # divide and assign
      for i, rand_num in enumerate(random_num_size):

          rand_set = set(np.random.choice(idx, rand_num, replace=False))
          idx = list(set(idx) - rand_set)
          dict_users[i] = rand_set
    
    else: #if all the samples are not used, then assign all the remaining unused samples to the last client
      for i, rand_num in enumerate(random_num_size):
          if(i==clients-1):
            dict_users[i] = idx #assign all the remaining samples to the last client
          else:
            rand_set = set(np.random.choice(idx, rand_num, replace=False))
            idx = list(set(idx) - rand_set)
            dict_users[i] = rand_set

    return dict_users

  else: #each client has the same number of samples   
    for i in range(clients):
        dict_users[i] = set(np.random.choice(idx, samples_per_client, replace=False))
        idx = list(set(idx) - dict_users[i])
    
    return dict_users
```

For example, if I apply this function to a dataset, I obtain this:

```
{0: {65536,
  65540,
  5,
  65544,
  13,
  15,
  65552,
  32785,
  65553,
  18,
  ...
{1: {8,
  150,
  ...
```

Now, starting from this dictionary, I want to obtain the original dataset split as stated by the dictionary. For example dataset0 will have the samples 65536, 65540, and so on, dataset1 will have 8, 150 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through all the keys in the dictionary you can you the .keys() method the get all the keys. You can then use a loop to go through each key and obtain each set in the dictionary.

Comment: If I do my_dict.keys() It returns this: `dict_keys([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])` that basically are all the splits (i split the dataset in 10). What I have to do with this?

Comment: You loop through that key array and to access the set at that key you would use my_dict[key], just like accessing an index of an array.